# Probability of getting white balls from urns

Tags: probability, combinatorics

QUESTION: An urn $A$ contains $3$ white balls and $4$ black balls. $2$ balls are drawn from urn $A$ and without seeing the colour and we introduce them in urn $B$ (which was empty). Later, a ball is drawn randomly from each urn.

a) Find out the probability that the ball drawn from urn $A$ is white.

b) Find out the probability that the two balls drawn are white.

BELOW IS MY SOLUTION. Is it correct?

a) Let $w$ the event of drawing a white ball and $b$ the event of drawing a black ball. The probabilities for the events of two drawings from urn $A$ are:

$\begin{array}{lll}
P(\{ ww \}) &=& \displaystyle \frac{3}{7} \cdot \frac{2}{6} = \frac{1}{7}, \quad P(\{ wb \}) = \displaystyle \frac{3}{7} \cdot \frac{4}{6} = \frac{2}{7}, \\
P(\{ bw \}) &=& \displaystyle \frac{4}{7} \cdot \frac{3}{6} = \frac{2}{7}, \quad P(\{ bb \}) = \displaystyle \frac{4}{7} \cdot \frac{3}{6} = \frac{2}{7} \\
\end{array}$

Let $W_A$ the event of drawing a white ball from urn $A$ after $2$ drawings. By total probability theorem:

$\begin{array}{lll}
P\left( W_A \right) & = & \displaystyle P\left(  \{ ww \} \right) \cdot P\left(W_A | \{ ww \} \right) + P\left(  \{ wb \} \right) \cdot P\left(W_A | \{ bn \} \right) + \\
&& P\left(  \{ bw \} \right) \cdot P\left(W_A | \{ bw \} \right) + P\left(  \{ bb \} \right) \cdot P\left(W_A | \{ bb \} \right)  \\
& = & \displaystyle \frac{1}{7} \cdot \frac{1}{5} + \frac{2}{7} \cdot \frac{2}{5} + \frac{2}{7} \cdot \frac{2}{5} + \frac{2}{7} \cdot \frac{3}{5} = \frac{1+4+4+6}{35}=\frac{15}{35} = \frac{3}{7} \\
\end{array}$

Consequently, the probability that the ball drawn from urn $A$ is white is $\displaystyle \frac{3}{7}$.

b) Let be the following events:

$\begin{array}{lll}
W_B & = & \{ \text{Get white ball from urn $B$ after $2$ drawings} \} \\
W_A \cap W_B & = & \{ \text{Get $2$ white balls after $2$ drawings} \} \\
\end{array}$

By total probability theorem:

$\begin{array}{lll}
P\left( W_A \cap W_B \right) & = & \displaystyle P\left( \{ bb \} \right) \cdot P\left(W_A \cap W_B | \{ bb \} \right) + P\left(  \{ bn \} \right) \cdot P\left(W_A \cap W_B | \{ bn \} \right) + \\
&& P\left(  \{ nb \} \right) \cdot P\left(W_A \cap W_B | \{ nb \} \right) + P\left(  \{ nn \} \right) \cdot P\left(W_A \cap W_B | \{ nn \} \right)  \\
& = & \displaystyle \frac{1}{7} \cdot \frac{1}{5} \cdot \frac{2}{2} + \frac{2}{7} \cdot \frac{2}{5} \cdot \frac{1}{2} + \frac{2}{7} \cdot \frac{2}{5} \cdot \frac{1}{2} + \frac{2}{7} \cdot \frac{3}{5} \cdot \frac{0}{2} = \frac{1+2+2}{35}=\frac{5}{35} = \frac{1}{7} \\
\end{array}$

The probability that the two balls drawn are white is $\displaystyle \frac{1}{7}$.

Comment: You changed your notation for the final calculation, which makes your work hard to follow.  That said, you seem to have obtained the correct answers to both questions.

Answer (score 1):

Given the solutions, we are hinted that the procedure of choosing $1$ or $2$ white balls does not affect the answer.

$$ \frac {3 \choose 1} {7 \choose 1} = {3 \over 7} $$

$$ \frac {3 \choose 2} {7 \choose 2} = {1 \over 7} $$

This makes sense.

Let's think to a deck with red an black cards. It does not matter how much we shuffle, cut or re-shuffle before we randomly turn two cards down side up and reveal the color.